# Load test dropwizard endpoint

Tags: go, load-testing, dropwizard

My Dropwizard configuration is as follows :

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
  minThreads: 50
  type: default
  maxThreads: 1024
  maxQueuedRequests: 1024
  gzip:
    enabled: true
    minimumEntitySize: 128B
    bufferSize: 8KB
    deflateCompressionLevel: 9
    includedMethods: [POST, GET]
```

I wrote a simple go code to load test this endpoint to find out the max RPS this can sustain.

```
func init() {
    // Customize the Transport to have larger connection pool
    defaultRoundTripper := http.DefaultTransport
    defaultTransportPointer, ok := defaultRoundTripper.(*http.Transport)
    if !ok {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("defaultRoundTripper not an *http.Transport"))
    }
    defaultTransport := *defaultTransportPointer // dereference it to get a copy of the struct that the pointer points to
    defaultTransport.MaxIdleConns = 500
    defaultTransport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 450

    myClient = &http.Client{Transport: &defaultTransport}
}

//HitHelloWorldService ...
func HitHelloWorldService() {
    fmt.Println("Hitting the Hello World Service")
    resp, err := myClient.Get(helloWorldEndpoint)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while hitting endpoint : %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

I have integrated prometheus with dropwizard and have used grafana to plot the RPS. To be very sure of the RPS.

Now the problem is that with the following go code calling the above function.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello !! Starting with go-client to benchmark dropwizard endpoints")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 400; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go httpclients.HitHelloWorldService()
    }

    wg.Wait()

}
```

I get the below error.

```
Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloWorld: read tcp 127.0.0.1:53576->127.0.0.1:8080: read: connection reset by peer
```

The max throughput I have been able to achieve is a max of 300 RPS.

Note : I am running this code on a local mac machine. Configuration is as follows :

Memory : 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Processor : 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloWorld: read tcp 127.0.0.1:53567->127.0.0.1:8080: read: connection reset by peer

How can I acheive higher RPS on my local mac machine. How can I fix the : **connection reset by peer** issue.

Comment: It could be caused by any number of things; it seems likely this is the server's mode of failure under excessive load. However, it's worth noting that this test tells you very little, because the load source and the server are running on the same machine, sharing resources. An effective load test must separate the two.

Answer (score 0):

Well could achieve 15000 RPS without changing anything at the Dropwizard level. But rewrote the go code. This time I used a worker pool.

```
const (
    numJobs    int = 5000000
    numWorkers int = 150
)

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- bool) {
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Processing Job No : %v\n", j)
        httpclients.HitHelloWorldService()
        results <- true
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello !! Starting with go-client to benchmark dropwizard endpoints")

    jobs := make(chan int, numJobs)
    results := make(chan bool, numJobs)

    for w := 1; w < numWorkers; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 1; j <= numJobs; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }

    close(jobs)
    for a := 1; a <= numJobs; a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

[Grafana graph capturing the RPS and ResponseTime of the endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBVYV.png)

This did circumvent the problem , but still not sure why **connection reset by peer issue** came the first time.